# ¿Orientacion basica de acceso a carpetas y archivos en Red Local c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual, studio

Muy buenas tardes.

Tengo conocimientos intermedios en programación de c#, y me encuentro con un problema, y es que, tengo una aplicación para un negocio pequeño en la que necesito acceder a archivos (una DB en QLite) que se encuentran en una ubicación de red local, pero no tengo la mas mínima idea de como implementarlo, tengo conocimiento de redes, como los protocolos TCP, FTP, el funcionamiento de IP local y publica, puertos, etc.

Tal cual, lo que estoy buscando y mi consulta es, ¿Donde puedo conseguir documentación a  la cual consultar y donde pueda aprender a acceder a archivos en red local desde c# en entorno windows?

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio y mi aplicación es en WPF (XAML) y c#, después de una intensa búsqueda y pocos resultados en español, me aparece que debo usar **net use** pero desconozco completamente la clase y como implementarla, así como su funcionamiento.

Estoy utilizando el System.IO y se que puedo acceder al directorio desde el UNC.
Por ejemplo:

`\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath\file.text`

Pero cuando la carpeta esta protegida por usuario y contraseña, debo proporcionar las credenciales en otra clase del tipo net, y es aquí donde me pierdo, ya que no se como continuar.

En resumen, me gustaría aprender a utilizar los recursos disponibles para manejo de archivos en red local, comprobar conexiones y establecerlas, verificar equipos disponibles, crear, modificar y eliminar archivos en la red.

De antemano agradezco la atención prestada.
Un cordial saludo!

Comment: Con "CREDENCIALES" te refieres a las credenciales de usuario de Windows (credenciales de red)?

Comment: Tampoco especificas si estás en un DOMINIO o simplemente trabajan todos dentro de la misma red LAN. Eso variará la respuesta que te podemos dar.

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Así es, me refiero a las credenciales de usuario, y los equipos trabajan en la misma red LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de copiar el archivo desde la red a la computadora local donde se esta ejecutando el software es la siguiente:

```
string archivoCompartido= 
@"\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath\file.text";
string nombreArchivo= Path.GetFileName(archivoCompartido),
string destino = @"C:\Destino";
File.Copy(archivoCompartido, Path.Combine(destino , nombreArchivo));
```

Si el problema es que esa ruta no puede ser accedida desde el software como mencionas puedes utilizar `NET USE` que sirve para crear una `Unidad Virtual`, osea como `C:` o `D:`, pero en este caso seria algo como `Y:`, o la letra que tu quieras y esta seria una conexion directa a `\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath\`

Despues de crear el directorio virtual con `NET USE` el codigo seria algo asi:

```
string archivoCompartido= 
@"Y:\file.text";
string nombreArchivo= Path.GetFileName(archivoCompartido),
string destino = @"C:\Destino";
File.Copy(archivoCompartido, Path.Combine(destino , nombreArchivo));
```

Porque ahora `Y:` es un directorio virtual que apunta a `\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath\`

**Y...¿Como haces que `Y:` apunte a `\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath\`?**

Te explico la parte de `NET USE`

Tendras que correr un comando en `CMD` o `PowerShell`, y tener un usuario y password con acceso a la ruta de red que quieras mapear, para esto te recomiendo primero que intentes entrar desde la computadora loca a la ruta utilizando el explorador de windows esto para validar si te pide o no contraseña, si te pide usuario y contraseñá utiliza el comando con usuario y contraseña, si no con el mas simple se puede realizar.

Recomiendo que abras CMD o powershell con permissos de administrador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no necesitas usuario y contraseñas para acceder a la ruta:

```
net use Y: "\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath" /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Si no necesitas usuario y contraseñas para acceder a la ruta:

```
net use Y: "\\NameLocalMachine\directoryPath" password/USER:usuario /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Una vez mapeada la ruta, esta aparecera en la lista de unidades como si fuera una unidad mas, pero en realidad es una unidad virutal que apunta a una carpeta en la red.

Puedes utilizar `NET USE` y dar enter en `CMD` para ver que rutas tienes mapeadas, en caso de algun error puedes utilizar `net use del` (no estoy 100% segura cual es la sintaxis para el comando) para eliminar el mapeo y volver a crearlo despues, tambien puedes utilizar `net use ?`  para ver ayuda sobre los comandos

NOTA: Puedes revisar este link para mas informacion sobre NET USE [Script Batch - Conectar unidad de red](https://www.portalmastips.com/script-batch-conectar-a-unidad-de-red-automaticamente-con-un-archivo-bat-map-network-drive/)

Comment: Impresionante, tengo bastante tiempo investigando el tema y esta respuesta me sirve cantidad para entender la base de lo que estoy haciendo, ahora me encuentro investigando si la DB SQLite me permite conectarme de manera remota directo al DB o es necesario crear una aplicacion cliente-servidor donde servidor este conectado a la DB y clientes solo hagan peticion al servidor y ahorrarme ese lio.

Te agradezco enormemente tu ayuda, continuo investigando.

Comment: No he trabajado con bases de datos de SqLite como para conectarte en red, pero si estas en un entorno de windows porque no utilizas sql express? es gratis y se puede trabajar en red con esta y te ahorras todo esto de copiar el archivo o acceder a el desde la red.  Aunque por otra parte tambien podrias hacer una web o api y exponer solo los datos que quieres compartir, tambien podrias utilizar SignalR para conectar todo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu mensaje Cristina.

En relacion a lo que me comentas la intención del programa es, manejar la base de datos para un punto de venta e inventario, al mismo tiempo entregar reportes y consultas directamente desde una aplicación móvil, para fines de pruebas, me era necesario colocarla en una red local para revisar el estado de la DB conforme se interactuaba con ella desde los equipos en los que instale el programa, aunque lo que voy a terminar haciendo es crear un servidor el cual este conectado a la DB y que este despache la información a los clientes.

Comment: Si tiene mas sentido que tengas las cosa en un server